# Deleting an element from a linked list error

Tags: linked-list

I'm trying to delete an element from a singly linked list using a boolean method with the value as a parameter. It works fine when the element is inside the List. But not when the List doesnt contain the value given as the parameter.
Thanks in advance.

```
public boolean remove (String content) {
        Boolean elementFound = false;
        Node it = front;
        while (it != null) {
            if (front.data == content) {
                front = it.next; // Change head
                return true;
            }
            else if (it.next.data == content)
            {
                it.next = it.next.next;
                return true;
            }
            else
                it = it.next;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The error I get when I try the executing the function with a value that's not inside the List.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "data" because "it.next" is null
    at list.List.remove(List.java:88)
    at list.List.main(List.java:163)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':List.main()'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

The main method:

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        List list = new List();

        list.add("10");
        list.add("12");
        list.add("22");
        list.add("33");

        list.remove("12");

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're encountering is due to a `NullPointerException` when the list doesn't contain the value you're trying to remove. This occurs because you're accessing `it.next.data` without checking if `it.next` is `null`.

To fix this, you need to modify your code to handle the case when `it.next` is `null`.

```
public boolean remove(String content) {
    if (front == null) {
        return false; // Empty list, nothing to remove
    }

    if (front.data.equals(content)) {
        front = front.next; // Change head
        return true;
    }

    Node current = front;
    while (current.next != null) {
        if (current.next.data.equals(content)) {
            current.next = current.next.next;
            return true;
        }
        current = current.next;
    }

    return false;
}
```